# Searching buffer string using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, buffer, revit-api

I have an Revit `.rvt` file (which is a `.7z` file under the hood), which I know contains a specific phrase within the first 30,000 bytes. I've attempted to use Nodejs to read it to a buffer, convert it to a string, and then search for the index of the phrase, but it always returns `-1`. If I print the string to the console, I see the words I'm looking for.

What am I missing?

Example Function:

```js
async function findPhraseIndex(path){
    const fileHandle = await open(path, 'r');

    const read = await fileHandle.read(Buffer.alloc(30000), 0, 30000);
    await fileHandle.close()

    const bufferString = read.buffer.toString('utf8');

    const index = bufferString.indexOf('Format');

    return index;
}
```

Example Data:

```
�P�Ԧ��♀��↕lkH)��R,8�♣0�EJ�→�)�PWԀ^Q¶�7At;♂o�(����↕v�&y�|���Z�♥��xa6���@K�∟Iɟ���A�<��ޛ0��☻Y�Ҫ��@.��oG�9�R�
ڃ♫UΧ�40��@���C���→♦�K^�F��r▲p��z���B/O⌂����k�1,�c��x�c�Z��♣��\*]um�t�
[1] a꒷���K;v��68�Ӵ♠�ꭇ�#�▬o�&�3�#�Ƅ��¶↓�⌂�↨Ҙ�}�J�ӤQ����S)��N�T�☼►g\)���n�▲��O^¶�"���►�����Da�♀H/�EZ7�♥�ݠ7ԁs��e��W�觌Z���7ճ-�T↨{�X���u�⌂��{h�⌂���o�▼�▼PK☺☻¶¶ ����W'☻�♣~C
915665c-dc15-4f6d-8dd6-51ebaf9d8c32.project.xmlP♫♦2022↕20210224_1515(x64)mC:\AC\Github\revit-family-property-updater-electron\RevitAddIns\FamilyParameterManager\SampleFiles\sample.rvt♥$00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000♥ENU☺$4badad54-ec6a-4af8-be09-5fecedec44dd$4badad54-ec6a-4af8-be09-5fecedec44dd☺1$00000000-
0000-0000-0000-000000000000♫Autodesk Revit►RevitApplication
[1] Worksharing: Not enabled
[1] Username:
[1] Central Model Path:
[1] Format: 2022
[1] Build: 20210224_1515(x64)
[1] Open Workset Default: 3
[1] Project Spark File: 0
[1] Central Model Identity: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
[1] Locale when saved: ENU
[1] All Local Changes Saved To Central: 0
[1] Central model's version number corresponding to the last reload latest: 1
[1] Central model's episode GUID corresponding to the last reload latest: 4badad54-ec6a-4af8-be09-5fecedec44dd
[1] Unique Document GUID: 4badad54-ec6a-4af8-be09-5fecedec44dd
[1] Unique Document Increments: 1
[1] Model Identity: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
[1] IsSingleUserCloudModel: False
[1] Author: Autodesk Revit
[1] ClientAppName: RevitApplication
[1] t
[1] ClientAppName: RevitAppO♣<?xml version="1.0"?>
[1] <TransmissionData isTransmitted="false" userData="" version="5"><ExternalFileReference><ElementId>117704</ElementId><ExternalFileReferenceType>Keynote Table</ExternalFileReferenceType><LastSavedPath>RevitKeynotes_Imperial_2004.txt</LastSavedPath><LastSavedAbsolutePath>C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\RVT 2022\Templa
tes\English-Imperial\RevitKeynotes_Imperial_2004.txt</LastSavedAbsolutePath><LastSavedPathType>Relative to Library Locations</LastSavedPathType><LastSavedLoadState>Not Found</LastSavedLoadState><DesiredPath>RevitKeynotes_Imperial_2004.txt</DesiredPath><DesiredPathType>Relative to Library Locations</DesiredPathT
ype><DesiredLoadState>Loaded</DesiredLoadState></ExternalFileReference><ExternalFileReference><ElementId>306703</ElementId><ExternalFileReferenceType>Assembly Code Table</ExternalFileReferenceType><LastSavedPath>UniformatClassifications.txt</LastSavedPath><LastSavedAbsolutePath>C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\RVT 2022\
Templates\English-Imperial\UniformatClassifications.txt</LastSavedAbsolutePath><LastSavedPathType>Relative to Library Locations</LastSavedPathType><LastSavedLoadState>Not Found</LastSavedLoadState><DesiredPath>UniformatClassifications.txt</DesiredPath><DesiredPathType>Relative to Library Locations</DesiredPathT
ype><DesiredLoadState>Loaded</DesiredLoadState></ExternalFileReference></TransmissionData>
[1] ☻♦♦♦♦♦♦
[1] b↓"♣→☺☺C☺☺☺☺☻☻♦♦♦♦♦♦
[1] ☻   �!►b↓"♣�▼♂Z�
```

Comment: Isn't the file data in your .7z file compressed?

Comment: Apparently not, based on what happens when I stringify the content. Not all of it, anyways. I don't know why it behaves the way it does, but the output I'm showing above is fairly consistent.

Comment: Can you provide download access to a representative file?  I'm not sure what you expect us to be able to do if we can't see one of the files.  If it's a .7z file, why don't you use a .7z library to unpack it?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, afaik, the RVT file format uses OLE storage, aka [COM Structured Storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_Structured_Storage). Maybe some parts of it are `7z` compressed and others are not. The Building Coder shares various examples showing how to extract useful parts of the data from that file format, especially the RVT file version:

- [RVT file version using Python `rvtver.py`](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2008/10/rvt-file-version.html)
- [RFA file version using Python `rvtver.py`](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2009/06/rfa-version-grey-commands-family-context-and-rdb-link.html#1)
- [C# Revit OLE Storage viewer](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/06/open-revit-ole-storage.html)
- [Basic File Info and RVT file version via C# console application](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/01/basic-file-info-and-rvt-file-version.html#5)
- [Reading an RVT File without Revit](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/02/reading-an-rvt-file-without-revit.html)
- [Automatically Open Correct RVT File Version](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2020/05/automatically-open-correct-rvt-file-version.html#4)

Maybe the information you are searching for can be read in a similar manner, and using a slightly less hacky approach than just searching randomly for a given string of bytes.